# Как определить, по какому полю произошло нажатие мыши?

Tags: c#, windows, wpf, xaml, visual-studio

Пишу шахматы на WPF, доску нарисовать смог, обработчик события нажатия мыши прикрепил, а вот **как в обработчики определить, по какой именно клеточке доски нажал пользователь**, придумать не могу. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать?

Код:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="ChessDemo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ChessDemo"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="600">

    <Window.Resources>

        <!-- Chekerboard pattern brush -->
        <DrawingBrush x:Key="Checkerboard" Stretch="None" TileMode="Tile" Viewport="0,0,2,2" ViewportUnits="Absolute">
            <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                <DrawingGroup>
                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="Black">
                        <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                            <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,2,2" />
                        </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                    </GeometryDrawing>
                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="White">
                        <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                            <GeometryGroup>
                                <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,1,1" />
                                <RectangleGeometry Rect="1,1,1,1" />
                            </GeometryGroup>
                        </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                    </GeometryDrawing>
                </DrawingGroup>
            </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        </DrawingBrush>

    </Window.Resources>

    <!-- Main Window Content -->
    <Viewbox >
        <ItemsControl Name="ChessBoard">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel >
                <ItemsPanelTemplate >
                    <Canvas   Width="8" Height="8" Background="{StaticResource Checkerboard}" MouseDown="Canvas_MouseDown" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Pos.X}" />
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Pos.Y}" />
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Viewbox>

</Window>
```

Код С# (ничего не менял, кроме добавления обработчика события):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace ChessDemo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Canvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            string t = " Как узанть на каком квадратике кликнули?";
            string str = t;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А почему бы вам не глянуть на `sender`? Скорее всего, `sender`'ом будет нужный `Canvas`, так что

```
((Canvas)sender).DataContext
```

даст вам viewmodel нужной клетки.

Comment: Спасибо. Работает.

Comment: @vvtvvtvvt: Пожалуйста!